# Clone/mirror image path to another element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to install a Jquery plugin called FancyBox to my client's pure HTML site. It is only using a very light CMS that can change a visible image.

However, the syntax for FancyBox is the following:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_1.jpg">
<img   src="small_image_1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

There is a different path for the big and small image, which makes it impossible to change the main image.

Is there a way to make jquery clone the path of `img` to the `a` tag's `href`?

Comment: So you want the `href` attribute of the `<a>` element to bet set by the `<img>` elements source?

Comment: Exactly. The CMS changes the `img` element's source, but not the `a`'s `href` attributte, which results in the new image opening the old one.

Comment: How many items are you doing this for? I'm assuming you want this done upon load, correct?

Comment: Small amounts, maybe 3 items. Yes, upon load, or at latest, on click of the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```
$('a.fancybox').attr('href',function(){
    return $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('small', 'big'); //find its child img and returns it src
});
```

Comment: Include it in a `$(document).ready()` so it loads right after the page finished loading.

**JS Fiddle Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/sja8ksk1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery like :

```
$('a.fancybox').attr('href',$('img').attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgPath = $('img').attr('src');

$('a.fancybox').attr('href', imgPath);
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more.

Comment: This won't work. He needs it to replace `small` with `big`.

Comment: JQuery attr() is used to get and set an attribute for an object.

using this in the first line it give the img src value whereas in the second line it sets the a href value.

Comment: if he wants the otherway around samething would work by changing:
var href  = $('a.fancybox').attr('href');
 $('img').attr('src', href);